# Iquidus JSON settings for Blockchain Explorer

Tags: blockchain, altcoin, altcoin-development, blockexplorer

I did a fork from litecoin into my own altcoin and I am trying to get it on a blockchain explorer to run realtime on a website. I chose an open source blockchain explorer called Iquidus which was recommended by one of the members in this community:

https://github.com/iquidus/explorer

I have followed the guide up to the point where I must adjust the settings.json file to customize it to by particular altcoin.

https://gist.github.com/zeronug/5c66207c426a1d4d5c73cc872255c572

The problem is that I am not too sure which information that needs to be adjusted in the file as it is not explicit in the instructions on what needs to be adjusted; for example, how do you know the blockhash, txhash, address, supply, which passwords and users that must be used, the instance, etc. Some values are subject to change so I am unsure where to set these values.

I am new to cryptocurrencies and I am trying to learn. My question is if there is a guide to help with modifying the settings.json file for my altcoin? Is there any recommended literature that can help me with this endeavor? If any, is there an easier option for a blockexplorer that you'd recommend?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Mandatory `settings.json` changes

if not set correctly explorer will not work

have to dig in the code of your forked litecoind (daemon) to get them

```
genesis_tx
genesis_block
```

same settings as your litecoind daemon taken from litecoin.conf file

```
wallet
  host
  port
  user
  pass
```

mongo database, change if different than your settings

```
dbsettings
  user
  password
  database
  address
  port
```

make sure you set difficulty which for litecoin is POW

```
index
  difficulty
```

## Secondary changes

meaning that the explorer can start working without them but should be changed to reflect your coin

```
title
address
coin
symbol
port
```

for the api page look here for details https://github.com/iquidus/explorer/issues/130

```
api
  blockindex
  address
  txhash
  blockhash
```

if you want to get coin value from markets set correct values for

```
markets
```

For reference [settings.json.template](https://github.com/iquidus/explorer/blob/master/settings.json.template)